# Select SSL Routes serving up rails 4 static pages via highvoltage gem

Tags: ssl, ruby-on-rails-4, high-voltage

I have several static erb pages being served up in a ruby rails 4 site via the high voltage gem:

```
get '/about'    => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'about'
get '/contact'  => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'contact', :protocol => "https"
get '/privacy'  => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'privacy'
```

This all works well and good, except that the /contact route doesn't redirect or force SSL on, it is happy with whatever protocol is used.

I host the site on engine yard, attempting to put :force_ssl only or variants in the route line resulted in failed deployments - high voltage uses a slightly different set of arguments than normal routes so I suspect there is a conflict somewhere.

Anyone use highvoltage and SSL with rails 4 for select static pages (not the whole site)? Example routes line please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding the `HighVoltage#PagesController` see the [override section](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage#override) of the documentation.

It might look something like this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  include HighVoltage::StaticPage

  before_filter :ensure_secure_page

  private

  def ensure_secure_page
    if params[:id] == 'contact'
      # check to make sure SSL is being use. Redirect to secure page if not.
    end
  end
end
```

Next disable the routes that HighVoltage provides:

```
# config/initializers/high_voltage.rb
HighVoltage.routes = false
```

Then in your application's routes file you'll need to set up a new route:

```
# config/routes.rb
get "/pages/*id" => 'pages#show', as: :page, format: false
```